# Route53 domain name not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, domain-name, amazon-route53

I successfully pushed a Rails app to an EC2 instance and gave it an elastic IP. Then I created a hosted zone for the instance and copied the nameservers to my registrar, name.com. This was about 18 hours ago and I still wasn't able to connect to the site ([capstonesavings.com](http://www.capstonesavings.com)), and the AWS "health check" that I instantiated keeps saying "Failure: The health checker could not establish a connection within the timeout limit." After deleting the record sets and the hosted zone, I started all over again and get the same results. It has been a couple of hours and still nothing.

This is my first time doing this, so I need to know how long does it usually take for a domain to propagate? I've heard everywhere from 1 minute to 72 hours. Is there something I've done wrong? Do I have to be more patient? If so, what do I do to expedite this process?

My current whoIs...

[image: WhoIs]

Hosted Zone info....

[image]

Record sets...

[image]

Record for the A-Name...

[image]

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your DNS is OK, but the website/webserver is not responding.

The domain is resolving to the Ip address you specified, but the even when accessing the site by IP nothing comes up. I don't think you are having a route53 issue.

BTW: In my experience, from the US anyway, adding records to route53 DNS they usually get propogated within 10-15 minutes at most.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I forgot to mention I'm in the U.S. It has been well over 15 minutes at this point, about 2 hours since this second attempt. Where should I look to determine the bottleneck?

Comment: @B.Bulpett. If the DNS is resolving correctly, you may need to check your security group, firewalls, and web server configuration to see if it is configured correctly.

Comment: @datasage Thanks. I fixed the security group in my vpc security group settings for the instance. Now, I can navigate to the site via the elastic IP (54.xx.xx.xxx). That's great, but my domain **name** still won't point to that elastic IP. Based on the above record set does it look like it should be?

Comment: @B.Bulpett it correctly resolves and loads from here, so you've fixed the security group, the server is running, and you have the correct Route53 settings. If you are having trouble locally it's *your* machine's DNS, route53.

Comment: @tedder42 That was the problem indeed. Good show man! I didn't think ubuntu cached dns, but after reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2219/how-do-i-clear-the-dns-cache) on ubuntu Stack Exchange, I ran `sudo kill -HUP $(pgrep dnsmasq)` and my page loads now.